# Capture and list Globals in Lua Script

Tags: lua

How does one iterate thru an entire script capture a list of all globals.

I understand that _G is the environment table and it holds all globals, but it hold literally ALL globals. I  want the globals in my script only

Comment: Try [this script](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/e4ab3bfc777faf4482a1b3f3ae19181b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than `_G` being a global variable itself, `_G` is a runtime table (and so could only be listed at some point during a particular run). You're right that it would list globals that are set by the script as well as by the Lua state initialization and other scripts that are used.

One way to find the variable identifiers that the compiler would bind as globals is to use the `luac` commandline tool:

```
luac -l script.lua | grep [SG]ETGLOBAL
```

The second column gives the line number. The last column (comment) gives the identifier.

Comment: `[SG]ETGLOBAL` only works until Lua 5.1. For Lua 5.2+, use `[SG]ETTABUP.*_ENV`. See http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2012-12/msg00397.html.