# How to identify uninitialized variables in a Lua script, without running it

Tags: c++, lua

I'd like to be able to write some Lua code like this:

```
y=x+1
```

and be able to get the names of all variables (`x` and `y` in this case) so that I can read from/write to them in the calling C++ program. The problem is that `x` is uninitialized, so this chunk will not execute and therefore neither variable will appear in the globals table. My current work-around is to have the user explicitly declare that they want to initialize `x` externally (as well as *how* to initialize it), then I pre-pend the Lua script with an appropriate declaration for `x`, so that the final script looks like this:

```
x= /*some value calculated outside of the Lua script*/
y=x+1
```

Although this works, I'd really like to have a way to automatically list all uninitialized variables in the Lua code and present them to the user, instead of the user having to remember to explicitly declare them. A function that parses the Lua code without executing it would probably be what I want. I've tried the function `luaL_loadstring`, but `x` and `y` don't show up in the globals table.

Since this is a bit vague, I'll give an actual use case. My C++ code basically performs optimizations on functions, such as finding a root or a maximum. I want the user to be able to define custom functions (in the form of Lua scripts), which in general will have one or more inputs and one or more outputs. The user will define which parameters the optimizer should operate on. For example, the user may want to find the minimum of `y=x^2`. The way I'd like it to work is that the user writes a Lua script consisting of nothing more than `y=x^2`, and then tells the optimizer to vary `x` in order to minimize `y`. On each iteration of the optimizer, the current guess for `x` would be automatically pasted into the user script, which is then executed, and then the value of `y` is pulled from the Lua state to be fed back to the optimizer. This is how I have it working now, however it's a bit clumsy from a UX perspective because the user has to manually declare that `x` is a Lua variable. This gets tedious when there are many variables that require manual declaration. It would be much better if I could automatically scan the script and show the user a list of their undeclared variables so they could then use drag-and-drop and other GUI sugar to do the manual declaration.

Comment: Use this [utility](https://gist.github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/e4ab3bfc777faf4482a1b3f3ae19181b).  It is written in Lua, so you can easily modify it to return list of globals as Lua array instead of printing it to stdout.

Comment: You have a very weird use case there, so maybe it'd make some sense to explain at least roughly what you want to achieve, otherwise it will be really hard for people to figure out what the best solution for your problem is.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer I edited the question to (hopefully) show exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53545655/capture-and-list-globals-in-lua-script

Comment: @Carlton Solved any of the answers your question? Consider accepting/upvoting?

Answer (score 3):

Lua isn't meant to work like that. Lua/C interop is intended to be *collaborative*; it's not supposed to be that C can do whatever it wants.

Using your example, if you have a Lua script that is supposed to take a value from C and return that value + 1, then you spell that in Lua like this:

```
local x = ... --Get the first parameter to the chunk.
return x + 1  --Adds 1 to the value and returns it.
```

You compile this string into a Lua chunk and call it like a Lua function. You pass it the value you want to manipulate and get the return value from the Lua stack.

The idea is *not* that C code can just reach into a Lua script and shove data into it arbitrarily. The above chunk takes parameters from the user and provides return values to the user. That's typically how C interfaces with Lua.

Yes, you can write values to globals and have the Lua script read them, and write its "results" to globals that the external code reads. But this is not the most effective way to interact with scripts.

> I'd really like to have a way to automatically list all uninitialized variables

There's no such thing in Lua as an "uninitialized variable". Not in the way that you mean.

Yes, there are globals. But whether that global has a value or not is *not* something the Lua script can control. A global is *global* after all; you can set a global variable from *outside* of the script (for example, see `lua_setglobal`). If you do, then a script that reads from it will read the value you set. But it doesn't know anything about that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used the term "undefined" in place of "uninitialized". Basically, I want my users to write Lua code using undefined variables as necessary, then in a separate step, present them with a list of the undefined variables so they can decide how to initialize them. To complicate things, the actual initial numerical value may not be explicitly known to the user; it may be the result of some separate calculation that the user doesn't have direct access to. In that case, I need to dynamically generate code and inject it into to the user's script (unless there's a better way).

Comment: @Carlton: Why do you want it that way? That's not how Lua naturally works or is typically used. You're making your job harder than it needs to be by deliberately avoiding the interface mechanisms that Lua provides (parameters and return values), and instead trying to build off of concepts that Lua doesn't recognize ("undefined" is no more correct than "uninitialized" in Lua. It has no concept of either).

Comment: Well, the main reason is that I don't know any better, however a secondary reason is that I don't want to make users write more Lua code than necessary. Most user-defined functions are two or three lines of code, so having to wrap everything in a Lua function might get messy. Let me read up on chunks as functions, I may be able to automate the process of wrapping user-code into Lua functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a static code analyzer/Lua linter. Take a look at [Luacheck](https://github.com/mpeterv/luacheck):

> Luacheck is a static analyzer and a linter for Lua. Luacheck detects
>   various issues such as usage of undefined global variables, unused
>   variables, and values, accessing uninitialized variables, unreachable
>   code and more. Most aspects of checking are configurable: there are
>   options for defining custom project-related globals, for selecting set
>   of standard globals (version of Lua standard library), for filtering
>   warnings by type and name of related variables, etc. The options can
>   be used on the command line, put into a config or directly into
>   checked files as Lua comments.

There is also [Lualint](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaLint), and similar Lua linters for [Atom](https://atom.io/packages/linter-lua), [VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dcr30.lualinter), or your fav IDE.